# Grouping identical numbers in an Array List ( Big Java Ex 7.5)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I should approach this problem even with some pseudo code that the book gives as hints ( This chapter is about arrays and arrayLists). By the way this isn't homework, and I am self learning.

**Problem**

> A run is a sequence of adjacent repeated values. Write a program that
> generates a sequence of 20 random die tosses and that prints the die
> values, marking the runs by including them in parentheses, like this:
> 1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5) 6 3 1

**Hint in Book**

> Set a boolean variable inRun to false.
>
> For each valid index i in the  array list If inRun
>
> If values[i] is different from the preceding value Print ) inRun = False Else
>
> If values[i] is the same as the following
> value Print ( inRun = True Print Values; [i]

What I don't get is how the hint is really helping. Say we have multiple numbers like `2 2 2 2` Wont this just do something like `(2 2) 2 2`

Heres what I am trying so far

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
class seq
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    private Random randNum;
    private boolean inRun;
    public seq()
    {
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        randNum = new Random();
        inRun = false;
    }
    
    public void addToArrList()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
        {
            int addThisNum = randNum.nextInt(20)+1;
            nums.add(addThisNum);
        }
    }
    
    public void checkSides()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(nums.get(i) != nums.get(i-1))
            {
                inRun = false;
            }
            if(nums.get(i) == nums.get(i+1))
            {
                inRun = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "Array is:";
        if (output.)
    }
}
```

**ANOTHER ATTEMPT**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Seq
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    private Random randNum;
    public Seq()
    {
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        randNum = new Random();
    }
    public void fillArrList()
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
        {
            int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(20)+1;
            nums.add(thisRandNum);
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean inRun = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if (i < nums.size() - 1 && nums.get(i).equals(nums.get(i + 1))) {
                if (!inRun) {
                    result.append("(");
                }
                result.append(nums.get(i));
                inRun = true;

            } else {
                result.append(nums.get(i));
                if (inRun) {
                    result.append(")");
                }
                inRun = false;

            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}

public class Sequence{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Seq seqObj = new Seq();
        seqObj.fillArrList();
        System.out.println(seqObj.toString());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
85641520612614320473181113612

201362181920141020(1919)514920162914
```

ETC

Comment: That should work up until the last value, on the last value it will go out of bounds because there is no `nums.get(20)` (Arrays and Lists start at index 0).  Of course, this assumes you're adding/printing the parenthesis (which in the code you show is not happening).

Comment: Yeah it was just my thoughts I presented. I'm just wondering on how I would put the brackets, would I have to somehow insert them in the arraylist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they mean something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean inRun = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (i < nums.size() - 1 && nums.get(i).equals(nums.get(i + 1))) {
            if (!inRun) {
                result.append("(");
            }
            result.append(nums.get(i));
            inRun = true;

        } else {
            result.append(nums.get(i));
            if (inRun) {
                result.append(")");
            }
            inRun = false;

        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Also you probably want to generate Randoms between 1 and 6, i.e.

```
int addThisNum = randNum.nextInt(6) +1;
```

Comment: I've been doing this but for some reason it doesent work all the time, for example on one run I got 85641520612614320473181113612

Comment: Have you changed your random generation?
When it still generates numbers up to 20, it is for example possible that 111 is one 11 followed by a 1. When i enter your numbers as single-digits i get the expected output 8564152061261432047318(111)3612

Comment: Ah. Thanks!.  A later problem in the book says to extend this problem and only put brackets around the longest marking for example 1122333(4444), since those are four consecutive fours. Could you give me a hint on this?

Comment: You could iterate twice over the list, the first time to determine the longest run and then remember the indices of the first and last number of this run.
The second time you generate your result `String` and add the ( before the first index and the ) behind the second index.

Comment: Is it considered bad form to write lots of logic within the toString method?

Comment: I would create a new method which builds the `String` and performs the `System.out.println`.

Comment: I made a new question, can you check it out? I've been trying for a while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830199/find-largest-sequence-within-an-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Here `randNum.nextInt(20)+1;` you are generating a random value from 0 to 20 you need to generate a random value which need to contain only one digits,

in the for loop i begin with zero in the first condition you call `nums.get(i-1)` which is incorrect as i = 0 so i-1 will be -1

There more logic issues you can check them from the code above

```
package com.run;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Run {
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    private Random randNum;
    private boolean inRun;
    private StringBuffer sb;
    public Run(){
         nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         randNum = new Random();
         inRun = false;
         sb = new StringBuffer();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Run run = new Run();
        run.addToArrList();
        run.checkSides();
    }
    public void addToArrList()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
        {
            int addThisNum = randNum.nextInt(9)+1;
            nums.add(addThisNum);
        }
    }

    public void checkSides()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(nums.get(i) != nums.get(i-1))
            {
                if(inRun)
                    sb.append(")");
                inRun = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!inRun){
                    System.out.println(nums.get(i));
                    inRun = true;
                    sb.replace(sb.length()-1, sb.length(), "(" + nums.get(i-1));
                }
            }
            sb.append(String.valueOf(nums.get(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh totally forgot that arraylists had a replace method. Thanks!!

Comment: pay attention it s not the array list that i have used with the replace it s a stringbuffer

Comment: I see. Could you look at my new attempt and see where I messed up?

Comment: you need to change  int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(20)+1; by this int addThisNum = randNum.nextInt(9)+1; I have already write it in my answer you need to generate a random value containing only one digit

Comment: If it solve your problem please mark the question as solved

Comment: A later problem in the book says to extend this problem and only put brackets around the longest marking for example 1122333(4444), since those are four consecutive fours. Could you give me a hint on this?

Comment: can you put it in a new question, you have to struggle your mind to get the solution that's how you will learn (advice)